# Passing XML data to a stored procedure and getting return value from it c#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, stored-procedures

I am trying to pass `xml` data as parameter to a stored procedure and getting return value from the stored procedure. But for some reason, the stored procedure is only returning me the data from the last row and I would like to know how to fix that problem. This is what I tried so far.

C# Code:

```
string[] mobilenum = { "254720516010", "254718488944" };
List<string> regtoken = new List<string>();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    DataTable ts = new DataTable();
    ts.Columns.Add("MobileNumber", typeof(string));
    foreach (string c in mobilenum)
    {
        ts.Rows.Add(c);
    }

    DataSet dset = new DataSet();
    dset.Tables.Add(ts);
    string res = dset.GetXml();

    String con = @"Data Source=***********;Initial Catalog=Peace;User ID=*****;Password=****";

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(con))
    {

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("p_getPushToken1", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DetailRecord", res));
        using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            da.Fill(ds, "Dataitems");
        }

        if (ds != null)
        {
            if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
            {
                if (ds.Tables["Dataitems"].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables["Dataitems"].Rows)
                    {

                        regtoken.Add(dr["Token"].ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The value of res (XML) string is:

```
<NewDataSet>
  <Table1>
    <MobileNumber>254720516010</MobileNumber>
  </Table1>
  <Table1>
    <MobileNumber>254718488944</MobileNumber>
  </Table1>
</NewDataSet>
```

SQL SERVER STORED PROCEDURE:

```
USE [Peace]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER proc [dbo].[p_GetPushToken1]
(
    @DetailRecord   XML
)
as    
    SELECT
        MobileNumber,
        FirstName,
        LastName,
        Token
    FROM tb_Registration WHERE MobileNumber IN(
    SELECT  Customer.x.value('MobileNumber[1]', 'varchar(20)')
    FROM @DetailRecord.nodes('NewDataSet/Table1') AS Customer(x))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part - isolated - returns both mobile numbers:

```
DECLARE @DetailRecord XML=
N'<NewDataSet>
  <Table1>
    <MobileNumber>254720516010</MobileNumber>
  </Table1>
  <Table1>
    <MobileNumber>254718488944</MobileNumber>
  </Table1>
</NewDataSet>';

 SELECT  Customer.x.value('MobileNumber[1]', 'varchar(20)')
 FROM @DetailRecord.nodes('NewDataSet/Table1') AS Customer(x)
```

You are using this sub-select within an `IN`-clause to fetch **all records of `tb_registration`** where this mobile number is found.

This should work...

If you do not get the expected result I'd assume, that your comparisson on string level does not work properly. Might be, that the mobile number is somehow differently stored in your table (spaces, delimiter characters, varchar(20) might be to small).

### UPDATE

Try to place your SP's statement within a simple query window and use a `declare` like I've done it above to simulate the parameter. Do you get more than one row back?